# Cassandra - getaddrinfo ENOENT error thrown using nodejs module helenus

Tags: node.js, cassandra, cql

I have setup a session module that will check session data in cassandra if it has expired or not. However after a certain amount of time this error will be thrown...

```
 Error: getaddrinfo ENOENT
```

I haven't got a clue as to what is causing this error.

I'm using Helenus which is a nodejs module which allows me to connect and do CQL queries to Cassandra.

I have also noticed that the following object gets returned as well instead of the actual data from the cassandra column family...

```
{ _idleTimeout: 2000,
  _idlePrev: 
   { _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     ontimeout: [Function] },
  _idleNext: 
   { _idleNext: [Circular],
     _idlePrev: [Circular],
     ontimeout: [Function] },
  _onTimeout: [Function],
  _idleStart: Sat, 17 Mar 2012 02:19:57 GMT }
```

Comment: can you give me some more information on this.  i know you have switched to node-cassandra-client, but if this is an issue I would like to resolve it

Answer (score 0):

As no solution has been suggested for this problem I have decided to switch to the nodejs module cassandra-client.

As of yet I have not received any problems with it.

https://github.com/racker/node-cassandra-client